# Virtualmin Error: Failed to copy /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini to /var/www/vhosts

Tags: php, apache2, virtualmin

I’m trying to setup a new site on my server through Virtualmin and am receiving the following error:

```
Performing other Apache configuration ..
.. configuration failed : Failed to copy /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini to /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/etc/php5/php.ini : cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/etc/php5/php.ini': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which version of Virtualmin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions on the file /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini to 775, that worked for me.